# Why do these constructors run in this order?

Tags: java, object, constructor

I have learned that object should be created something like this `Class_name Object_name=new Classname()`. In my program, I created a super class named `sup` and a derived class named `der`. In my subclass constructor, I have created a object like this `sup obc = new der();`. Without any errors it compiled and gave output like this:

```
In Superclass with object passed as reference
In Superclass with no constructor
In derived class with no constructor
```

I did not understand how I got the output in this order. Why does this happen? Here is the complete code:

```
class sup {

  private int a, b, c;

  sup(sup ob) {
    System.out.println("In Superclass with object passed as reference");
    a = ob.a + 9;
    b = ob.b + 9;
  }

  sup(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  sup() {
    System.out.println("In Superclass with no constructor");
  }

}

class der extends sup {

  int d;

  der(der ob) {
    super(ob);
    sup obc = new der();
  }

  der() {
    System.out.println("In derived class with no constructor");
  }

  der(int a, int b, int c) {
    super(a, b);
    d = c;
  }
}

public class Test {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    der ob1 = new der(3, 4, 5);
    der ob2 = new der(ob1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure you stick to Java naming conventions, especially in these formative first programs. In Java we use `PascalCase` for class names, reserving `camelCase` for variables. Further, please format your code before posting.

Comment: Since i am new to java i will soon learn  Java naming conventions. @BoristheSpider

Comment: @Ashokkumar Instead of learning in future, you should try to edit now and learn.

Comment: @karthik Yeah. I have formatted the code little bit. from now on i will use proper naming conventions.

Comment: @Ashokkumar don't format code by hand! That's a fruitless task. Ask your IDE to autoformat it for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first call:

```
der ob1 = new der(3, 4, 5);
```

prints nothing, because first it calls:

```
der(int a, int b, int c) {
    super(a, b);
```

Which calls:

```
sup(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

Which has no `System.out.println` statements. None of the other constructors are called, because you **never explicitly** call them. The implicit `sup()` constructor is not called, because you've called `super(a, b)`.

---

The second call:

```
der ob2 = new der(ob1);
```

Calls this constructor:

```
der(der ob) {
    super(ob);
    sup obc = new der();
}
```

The first thing that happens is the super constructor here gets called:

```
sup(sup ob) {
    System.out.println("In Superclass with object passed as reference");
```

This is the **first thing** that gets printed. Then, the second line:

```
sup obc = new der();
```

is called, which calls this constructor:

```
der() {
    System.out.println("In derived class with no constructor");
}
```

However, there is an **implicit call** to `super();` here that is always called in subclasses, even if you do not write it. So we then call:

```
sup() {
    System.out.println("In Superclass with no constructor");
}
```

This gets printed, and finally `der`'s constructor can finish.

Note that if you **delete the no-argument constructor** of `sup`, `der` will no longer compile with the error:

> Implicit super constructor `ArrayListTest.sup()` is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Answer (score 6):

```
der(der ob) {
  super(ob);
  sup obc = new der();
}
```

The first thing this does is calling the superclass constructor `sup(sup obj)` (which prints the first output line), then the code (without any reason) allocates a `new der()`.

But in Java, the superclass default constructor is implicitly called before the subclass constructor, indeed `der()` constructor implementation could be seen as

```
der()
{
  super();
  System.out.println("In derived class with no constructor");
}
```

which explains second and third output line.

Answer (score 1):

The first `der` object calls the `super(a,b)` constructor which has no output. The second calls `sup(sup ob)` which gives the first line of output and then it also calls `new der()`, when the default constructor for a subclass is called the default constructor for its superclass is also called. That's where the 2nd line comes from. And then `new Der()` outputs the 3rd line.